# Not getting response data for certain images on google cloud vision API

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I have been using the google cloud vision API to get annotations and landmark recognition for a large number of images. However, there are a few in the set of images that I am indexing that are not getting any annotations.

I am using the Ruby SDK, here is a sample of the code that is retrieving annotations:

```
def send_request
   image_annotator.batch_annotate_images requests: [request]
end
```

```
def request
  {
    image: request_image,
    features: features
  }
end
```

```
def request_image
  if Rails.env.development?
    { content: photo_content }
  else
    { source: { image_uri: @photo.url } }
  end
end
```

Here is a sample URL for an image that worked:

```
"https://assets.picspree.com/variants/DyZUPPHeKvRJE1WJpHgTEDUd/f4a36f6589a0e50e702740b15352bc00e4bfaf6f58bd4db850e167794d05993d
```

Here is one for an image that did not work.

```
https://assets.picspree.com/variants/c5j4iJXBWrRv4PgVXHe26eeD/f4a36f6589a0e50e702740b15352bc00e4bfaf6f58bd4db850e167794d05993d
```

Here is a full sample request:

```
 {:image=>{:source=>{:image_uri=>"https://assets.picspree.com/variants/c5j4iJXBWrRv4PgVXHe26eeD/f4a36f6589a0e50e702740b15352bc00e4bfaf6f58bd4db850e167794d05993d}}, :features=>[{:type=>:LABEL_DETECTION}, {:type=>:LANDMARK_DETECTION}]}
```

The response I get back seems to be successful, but it provides no annotations of any kind. I do get annotations successfully when I upload the image into the Google Cloud Vision documentation and preview page at https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/drag-and-drop.

So perhaps the issue is image specific, but I can't find anything more specific than that. Any possible help out there?

Comment: What features type you send?

Comment: I requested label detection and landmark detection.

Comment: Please add the full request, also suggest to add document text detection to mimic the api

Comment: Here is the other code that makes up a request:

```
    def request_image
      if Rails.env.development?
        { content: photo_content }
      else
        { source: { image_uri: @photo.url } }
      end
    end
```

```
    def features
      [
        { type: :LABEL_DETECTION },
        { type: :LANDMARK_DETECTION }
      ]
    end
```

Comment: And a full sample request:
```
{:image=>{:source=>{:image_uri=>"https://assets.picspree.com/variants/PXgDFHmkcM4Zhw9UvCeLzeRK/f4a36f6589a0e50e702740b15352bc00e4bfaf6f58bd4db850e167794d05993d"}}, :features=>[{:type=>:LABEL_DETECTION}, {:type=>:LANDMARK_DETECTION}]}
```

Comment: Adding the DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION feature does not change the result, no annotations of any kind are provided.

Comment: Please edit the question and add request

Comment: I've updated the question as requested.

Comment: I'm trying to help you understand what is going wrong but I can't access the images, any chance to add them in other way?

Comment: Maybe this will help, here are a few pages that some of the images we've been trying to get annotated appear on:

https://picspree.com/en/photos/24020966-1229010
https://picspree.com/en/photos/23646486-1228874
https://picspree.com/en/photos/23533469-1228846

The image we are trying to annotate are the images that appear at the top centre of each of these pages.

Comment: Hey, u trying to find LABEL_DETECTION and LANDMARK_DETECTION both of them are not existing in your pics (and not the text_  I asked you to try), so u are not receiving this annotations not even in the demo API, the pic has faceAnnotations for example so this annotation exist in the Demo and I believe in your response.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I see that for the second image I provided, but the first image I looked at does get annotations for "Objects" in the AI preview page here https://cloud.google.com/vision/. What feature is needed to make those appear?

Comment: I believe it’s OBJECT_LOCALIZATION, see here https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/object-localizer